# scala error acessing stanford corenlp sentiment - local class incompatible

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to use the Stanford corenlp java library from scala. First error that I ran into was java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase.  No mention of a dependency on org.ejml is mentioned on the corenlp website nor do java code examples show an import.  However, I put the ejml jar in the /lib dir then import and I can create a matrix but when I try to access corenlp with the code below I get:

```
> run
[info] Running Sentiment 
Adding annotator tokenize
TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser    /englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.3 sec].
Adding annotator sentiment
[error] (run-main-19) edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException:    java.io.InvalidClassException: org.ejml.simple.SimpleBase; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7560584869544985034, local class serialVersionUID = -4908174115141247692
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Contents of my /lib

```
lib/
 EJML-core-0.28.jar
 EJML-dense64-0.28.jar
 EJML-simple-0.28.jar
 opencsv-3.6.jar
 stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar
 stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar
```

scala code

```
object Sentiment {

  import java.io.FileReader
  import java.util.Properties
  import com.opencsv._
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  // corenlp
  import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations
  import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
  import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree
  import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree
  import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap

  import org.ejml.simple._




def build_pipeline() = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment")
    val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
}

def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val pipeline = build_pipeline
    // additional code to go here

    }
}
```

Comment: The mismatching 'serialVersionUID' indicates mismatch between library versions, or possibly that the libraries were compiled with a different scala version than you are currently working with.

Comment: The library in question, ejml, is a java library from Google.  I started working backward through deprecated versions until v .21 which worked.  I also did find evidence of a dependency on ejml on the core-nlp web site. Thanks